# Realizar operaciones matematicas en tiempo real o a resultados de array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html5, array

Antes que todo un cordial saludo! Les cuento mi inconveniente: Tengo 2 planillas tipo listado de inventario **(Una es el origen de los datos y la otra debe imprimir los valores introducidos en la primera para ser enviados por correo electrónico)** la cosa es que los valores como el iva, sin iva, ganacia, llevan unas operaciones matemáticas cuyos resultados se deben ir imprimiendo en la ***Planilla 2*** a medida que los voy introduciendo en la ***Planilla 1*** ahora bien, cada planilla posee 70 filas de 9 campos cada una entonces en la ***Planilla 1*** extraigo los valores actuales de la misma desde la BD en un array y los muestro en inputs editables en los cuales el usuario edita su valor y estos se van imprimiendo en la ***Planilla 2*** usando la nueva funcion ***OUTPUT*** de HTML5 ***(Esto para que las impresiones de los valores en la Planilla 2 se vayan mostrando en tiempo real)...

La duda es si puedo realizar operaciones matématicas a esos valores mientras los voy pasando desde la **Planilla 1*** a la ***Planilla 2*** es decir, en lugar de mostrarse el valor introducido por el usuario en la ***Planilla 1***, debe mostrarse es el resultado de la operación (División, resta, multiplicacion) en la ***Planilla 2*** **(en tiempo real, cabiendo destacar que son 2 formularios diferentes en 2 planillas que se despliegan una sobre otra en la misma página porque se como hacer esto cuando los input son de un mismo formulario y estan juntos, ademas de ser netamente HTML5 y en mi caso necesito usar PHP)**, he buscado en varias partes y no encuentro nada, el efecto que pretendo obtener es como el de las fórmulas Excel, sería estupendo si me pudiesen ayudar, cualquier otro dato que necesiten me lo pueden solicitar. Anexo fragmentos relevantes del código:

```
    <?php

    require ('php/conexion.php');

    /* REALIZO CONSULTA PARA LA TABLA 1 Y LOS ALMACENO EN UN ARRAY */

    $consulta ="SELECT * FROM `planilla` ORDER BY `planilla`.`cod` ASC LIMIT 70";
    $result= mysql_query($consulta);

    $a = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($a<=70)
    {
    $a++; /* ESTA VARIABLE LA HE CREADO PARA QUE CADA DATO EXTRAÍDO DE LA CONSULTA POSEA UN "ID" DIFERENTE (EJM: valor1, valor2, valor3...) */
    ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['cod'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['producto'];?></td>

    <!-- EN ESTA LÍNEA APLICO LA FUNCIÓN DE HTML5 PARA ENVIAR LOS DATOS EN TIEMPO REAL A LA PLANILLA 2 -->
      <td>
        <form id="form_costo<?php echo $a?>" name="form_costo<?php echo $a?>" method="POST" oninput="<?php echo "re_costos" . $a?>.value=parseInt(<?php echo "costos" . $a?>.value)">
          <input type="number" id="<?php echo "costos" . $a?>" name="<?php echo "costos" . $a?>" value="<?php echo $row['costo'];?>" class="form-control">
        </form>
      </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    <!--- FIN de la TABLA 1 --->
```

Ahora les muestro como se van capturando en la tabla 2 que es donde necesito que se vayan ejecutando las operaciones matematicas en tiempo real. **O si hay manera de aplicarlo a los resultados de la consulta a la BD directamente a los resultados extraídos mediante el array también me serviría, es decir, quedaría descartado lo de "En tiempo real", me explico: Obtengo resultados mediante el array y a estos les voy aplicando las operaciones matemática (Si es que es posible claro) cualquiera de las 2 opciones me puede ser de ayuda. Gracias de antemano**

```
<!-- INICIO TABLA 2 --->
<?php   
require ('php/conexion.php');

/* AQUI REALIZO OTRA CONSULTA SÓLO PARA EXTRAER EL "CÓDIGO" Y LOS "PRODUCTOS" Y MOSTRARLOS EN UN ARRAY EN LAS PRIMERAS 2 COLUMNAS */

$consulta2 ="SELECT * FROM `planilla` ORDER BY `planilla`.`cod` ASC LIMIT 70";
$result2 = mysql_query($consulta2);

$b = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
if ($b<=70)
{
$b++; /* AQUI HE CREADO UNA VARIABLE PARA LA MISMA FUNCIONALIDAD DE LOS "ID" EN LA ANTERIOR */

$codigo = $row['cod']; /* ALMACENO CODIGO EN UNA VARIABLE */
$produc = $row['producto']; /* ALMACENO CODIGO EN UNA VARIABLE */

    echo "<TD>$codigo</TD>"; /* IMPRIMO CÓDIGO */
    echo "<TD>$produc</TD>"; /* IMPRIMO PRODUCTO */

/*  CON ESTA PORCIÓN DE CÓDIGO VOY IMPRIMIENDO LOS VALORES DE COSTO QUE EL USUARIO VAYA INTRODUCIENDO EN LA TABLA 1: <output form='form_costo$b' name='re_costos$b' for='costos$b'></output> */
/* EN LA SIGUIENTE LINEA PUEDEN VER COMO SE IMPRIMEN LOS VALORES DE COSTOS QUE SE VAN INTRODUCIENDO EN LA PLANILLA 1 Y ES DONDE NECESITO QUE EN LUGAR DE IMPRIMIR EL VALOR DIRECTAMENTE SE IMPRIMA EL RESULTADO DE LA OPERACION MATEMATICA */
    echo "<TD><output form='form_costo$b' name='re_costos$b' for='costos$b'></output></TD>";
?>
</tbody>
<?php
}
}
?>
<!-- FIN DE TABLA 2 --->
```

La respuesta del amigo me ayudó a imprimir el resultado del "Sin IVA", ya que obtengo el valor de PVP y lo divido entre 1,21 directamente. Ahora en este caso la pregunta sería ¿Como puedo asignar los valores obtenidos de una operación anterior a una variable para combinarla con otra operación? Ejemplo:

PVP **-** Resultado de "Sin IVA"

Comment: Quieres usar el valor que queda en los elementos `output` para una nueva operación? O quieres usar una fórmula distinta para llenar el output? Podrías dibujar, aunque fuera en un excel, lo que quieres obtener

Comment: Exacto amigo @amenadiel la idea es usar el valor que queda en los elementos output para una nueva operación con una formula diferente, por ejemplo: 

Digamos que he realizado una operación: pvp/1,21 y me arroja un resultado, en donde PVP sería un valor introducido por el usuario, entonces digamos que el resultado de esta operación lo quiero imprimir en su casilla correspondiente, pero a su vez debo usarlo para otras fórmulas como por ejemplo: pvp (El resultado que ya obtuve antes) - costo. Y esto me arrojaría un nuevo resultado y  así sucesivamente.

Comment: @amenadiel - ...(Continuación del comentario anterior) Algo así como funcionan las fórmulas de Excel justamente como has mencionado... De igual manera estoy intentando de otra manera (Usando Jquery) entonces a ver si puedo obtener algo parecido, si puedes ayudarme en una solución ya sea mediante este método o mediante el otro el cual puedes ver los detalles de lo que llevo avanzado en una nueva pregunta que he formulado te lo agradecería muchísimo. Un gran saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quisieras por ejemplo tener dos tablas, y que la modificación de datos en la primera alterase los valores en la segunda (por ejemplo, añadiéndoles un 18% de impuesto) está bien como lo estás haciendo:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>producto</td>
      <td>codigo</td>
      <td>valor neto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pan</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <form id="form_costo5" oninput="result5.value=parseInt(costo5.value)*1.18">
          <input type="number" name="costo5" value="0" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>queso</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <form id="form_costo4" oninput="result4.value=parseInt(costo4.value)*1.18">
          <input type="number" name="costo4" value="0" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<hr>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>producto</td>
      <td>codigo</td>
      <td>total con IVA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pan</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>
        <output form='form_costo5' name='result5' for='costo5'></output>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>queso</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>
        <output form='form_costo4' name='result4' for='costo4'></output>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Ahora, no entiendo para qué querrías hacer eso, si ya sabes el valor de `$row['costo']` puedes imprimir otra celda que contenga, por ejemplo  `1.18* $row['costo']`;

Pero, suponiendo que algunos valores vienen fijos desde la base de datos (por ejemplo el precio) y otros no vienen definidos, sí tendría sentido que el usuario completara los que están vacíos.

EDIT: acá te muestro un ejemplo en donde el ingreso de la **cantidad** modifica el valor de dos output: el total c/IVA y el neto.

```css
input {
width:auto;
max-width:121px;
}
output {
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:85px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>producto</td>
      <td>codigo</td>
      <td style="width:125px;">valor neto unitario</td>
      <td style="width:125px;">cantidad</td>
      <td >total c/IVA</td>
      <td >total neto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pan</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <form id="form_costo5" oninput="result5.value=Number(parseInt(cantidad5.value,10)*parseInt(costo5.value,10)*1.21).toFixed(3);neto5.value=Number(parseInt(cantidad5.value,10)*parseInt(costo5.value,10)).toFixed(3)">
          <input type="number" name="costo5" value="15" />
          <input type="number" name="cantidad5" value="0" />
        </form>
      </td>
       <td colspan="2">
        <output form='form_costo5' name='result5' onchange="alert(this.value)" >0</output>
        <output form='form_costo5' name='neto5' >0</output>
      </td>    
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>queso</td>
      <td>4</td>
     <td colspan="2">
        <form id="form_costo4" oninput="result4.value=Number(parseInt(cantidad4.value,10)*parseInt(costo4.value,10)*1.21).toFixed(3);neto4.value=Number(parseInt(cantidad4.value,10)*parseInt(costo4.value,10)).toFixed(3)">
          <input type="number" name="costo4" value="10" />
          <input type="number" name="cantidad4" value="0" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <output form='form_costo4' name='result4' >0</output>
        <output form='form_costo4' name='neto4' >0</output>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

De tu pregunta queda en el aire lo que pretendes hacer con esta tabla "actualizada en tiempo real". Porque supongo que querrás imprimirla o persistirla en alguna parte.

EDIT 2: Usando jQuery se simplifica toda esta operación. En la práctica puedes usar clases para definir genéricamente el mismo comportamiento para todas las filas:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.fila_calculo').on('change keyup','input',function() {
      var $tr=jQuery(this).closest('tr'),
          costo=$tr.find('.costo').val(),
          cantidad=$tr.find('.cantidad').val();
          $tr.find('.total').val(costo*cantidad*1.21);
          $tr.find('.neto').val(costo*cantidad);
  });
});
```

```css
input {
width:auto;
max-width:121px;
}
output {
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:85px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>producto</td>
      <td>codigo</td>
      <td style="width:125px;">valor neto unitario</td>
      <td style="width:125px;">cantidad</td>
      <td >total c/IVA</td>
      <td >total neto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fila_calculo">
      <td>pan</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td colspan="2">
          <input type="number" class="costo" value="15" />
          <input type="number" class="cantidad" value="0" />
        
      </td>
       <td colspan="2">
        <output class="total" >0</output>
        <output class='neto' >0</output>
       
      </td>    
     </tr>
    <tr class="fila_calculo">
      <td>queso</td>
      <td>4</td>
     <td colspan="2">
          <input type="number" class="costo" value="10" />
          <input type="number" class="cantidad" value="0" />
       
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <output class="total" >0</output>
        <output class='neto' >0</output>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Exacto amigo, lo que pasa es que lo que extraigo desde la base de datos son valores fijos, es decir, como la estructura inicial que verá el usuario al ingresar a la tabla (Estos datos no seran alterados, retomaran su valor inicial al enviar la tabla) y bueno pensé que había especificado que iba a hacer con los datos pero veo que se me pasó por alto jejeje... La idea es enviar los valores impresos en la ***Tabla 2*** o tabla destino por correo a 3 mails diferentes. Probaré lo que mecomentas y te cuento

Comment: modifiqué el segundo ejemplo para mostrar cómo se llenan dos output con el mismo form, y añadí un tercer ejemplo mostrando cómo se hace lo mismo con jQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias amenadiel, me sirvió mucho tu ejemplo :)